# Base64 code for my smart asset works on testnet but script gives a syntax error while creating the real asset. Any ideas?

Tags: smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I have created a smart asset script on ide.

I can create the smart asset on testnet with the code Base64 from ide. That works fine on testnet.

But when I try to create the real asset, smart asset script form gives "syntax error" for the base64 code. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your contract please, especially first three lines with directives.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a mismatch between the testnet and mainnet results.
Even encoding and decoding a same script 'true' gives different out and input for me.